# Некорректно суммирует элементы строки

Tags: java, java-8

Помогите разобраться с такой проблемой - мне нужно ввести целое число и на выходе получить сумму его элементов в двоичной системе.
Например, ввод: 9, вывод 2, так как 9 -- это `0b1001`, и сумма единиц составит 2.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1 = sc.nextInt();

        String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(num1);
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++) {
            char c1 = binary.charAt(i);
            sum =+c1;
            System.out.println(sum); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы забыли о том, что числовой ASCII-код символа '0' это 48 и числовой ASCII-код символа '1' это 49

Comment: Если бы забыл....-не знал( я совсем начианющий. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к комментарию @andreymal приведу полный ответ: действительно, вы складываете не нули и единицы двоичной записи, а их символьные коды, большие самих чисел ровно на 48 (код символа `0`). Это происходит, потому что коды символов назначаются в соответствии с кодовыми таблицами.
Вот пример кодовой таблицы ASCII (некоторые строки таблицы имеют пустые значения *char*, поскольку соответствующие им символы являются служебными и не имеют визуального представления, они попросту невидимы):

[image: ascii code page]

То есть все, что вам нужно - вычесть 48 из каждого элемента суммы. А еще проще вычитать `'0'`, ведь `char` это числа, и числовое значение `char` равно коду символа в той кодовой таблице, с которой работает ваша программа.

Пример правильного кода:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1 = sc.nextInt();

        String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(num1);
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++) {
            char c1 = binary.charAt(i);
            sum += c1 - '0'; // <--
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что я поменял местами `+` и `=` в вашей записи в строке, отмеченной стрелочкой. Вариант, предложенный вами, просто присваивает переменной `sum` значение `c1`, это совсем не то, чего мы хотим :)

---

#### К размышлению:

Я приведу гораздо более оптимальный вариант решения вашей задачи, а вы постарайтесь понять, что здесь происходит:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;

        while (num != 0) {
            sum += num & 1;
            num >>= 1;
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что этот вариант работает корректно только для неотрицательных чисел из-за особенностей представления в компьютере чисел меньших нуля.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. Попытаюсь разобраться )

Answer (score 1):

Дополнение к ответу @Стаса.

Для преобразования символа цифры в числовое значение необязательно применять вычитание `'0'`, так как существует библиотечный метод [`Character.getNumericValue(char ch)`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java8/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue-char-):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = sc.nextInt();

        String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(num);
        int sum = 0;
        for (char digit : binary.toCharArray()) {
            sum += Character.getNumericValue(digit);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Но наиболее лаконичный способ подсчёта единиц в двоичной записи целого числа состоит в том, чтобы воспользоваться другим библиотечным методом [`Integer.bitCount(int i)`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java8/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount-int-), так что весь код сведётся к "однострочнику":

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        System.out.println(Integer.bitCount(new Scanner(System.in).nextInt()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @progAlex1, если какой-то из ответов оказался наиболее полезным / красивым, его следует принять, поставив зелёную галочку (слева от ответа) -- это лучше, чем простое "спасибо" :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1 = sc.nextInt();

        String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(num1);
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++) {
            char c1 = binary.charAt(i);
            int binaryValue = c1 - '0';
            sum += binaryValue;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Подскажите для чего эта решающая строчка- int binaryValue = c1 - '0'; ? я еще начинающий так что прошу не судить строго)